# Custom Linux Hosting Control Panel in PHP - running commands as root

Tags: linux, centos, php, nginx

I want to work on a custom linux hosting control panel based on my experience in managing LEMP/LAMP stack. This is just a pet project. I believe I have ran into some hurdle.

The CP is being written in PHP and server by NginX as default server on port 8000.
I am not using any framework, just vanilla PHP.

In putty, logged in as root, I can get the system uuid like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# dmidecode -s system-uuid
997C4DE8-213B-4ACC-8E23-01E79D6CC12F
```

When I try this in PHP with the following script:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('dmidecode -s system-uuid 2>&1'));
```

I get the following:

> sh: dmidecode: command not found

How can I execute that above command get the output in PHP?

Nginx/PHP-FPM is running as user `nginx`. Do i need to add nginx user to root group?

I want to be able to execute very specific commands like: `/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart` from my control panel (to restart php-fpm gateway).

How can I achieve this? What are my options? How does control panel like cPanel, DirectAdmin, etc... do it?

---

I have tried the following method also. Installed `sudo` and used the `sudo visudo` command and added the following lines at the end:

```
nginx    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD:/path/to/php_shell.sh
Defaults:nginx        !requiretty
```

and the content of `php_shell.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

Now, I tried to execute it like this:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('sudo sh /path/to/php_shell.sh 2>&1'));
```

I get: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: The order of rules in /etc/sudoers is significant.  i.e. you probably need to move that `!requiretty` above the nginx line.

Answer (score 0):

`dmidecode` is usually in directory `/usr/sbin` and this is not always in the PATH, so from php use the full path, found with `type -p dmidecode`, eg `/usr/sbin/dmidecode`.

As to your sudo, you did `sudo sh ...` instead of `sudo /path/to/php_shell.sh` so your NOPASSWD entry did not match. However, it would be better to list explicitly in your sudo file the command and its arguments, rather than allowing a general purpose script to run as root. So use eg

```
Defaults:nginx        !requiretty
nginx ALL NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/dmidecode -s system-uuid
```

If you have several commands you need to run as root, put them on the same
line separated by a comma.